# Using SQL Order By on two tables logic Explaination?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-order-by

[image: SQL Order By multiple fields]
I have an occurring question regarding the logic of Order by,
In Datacamp intermediate sql course it was mentioned I can use order by on two fields But the second field will be a tie breaker,

My question is what will be SQL logic if the order by on feature 1 is not the same, for instance if you look at the example what if the 3 movies did have different wins number and ordered accordingly then the imdb_score is opposite or different from the wins order

ex lord of the rings : 12 wins BUt imdb score is 6
Titanic : 11 wins but imdb score is 9

what data will be shown and the logic behind it

Comment: If there is no tie then there will be no tie-breaking and the 2nd order will not be taken into consideration..

Answer (score 2):

The best explanation I know for an `ORDER BY` with two columns or expressions is a phone book. A phone book is sorted like `ORDER BY last name, first name`. So it is sorted by last name, and within all the entries that have the same last name, it is sorted by first name.